# Foreign Data Wrappers, ogr_fwd layer Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dbf, foreign-data-wrapper

I have make correctly(it connects me) a Server with foreign data this way:

```
CREATE SERVER myserver
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER ogr_fdw
  OPTIONS (
   datasource 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\tmp\test\myfile.dbf',
    format 'ESRI Shapefile' );
```

Then i make a foreign table like this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE pt_test (
  "field1" integer,
  "field2" varchar,
  "field3" varchar,
  "field4" varchar,
  "field5" varchar)
  SERVER myserver
  OPTIONS (layer 'pt_two');
```

When i make a Select to pt_test, it gives me this error:

```
SQL Error: ERROR:  unable to connect to layer to "pt_two"
HINT:  Does the layer exist?
```

I dont now what is layer.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Run command `ogr_fdw_info -s "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\tmp\test\myfile.dbf"` this can provide list of layers in your file. Select existed one and pass it into 'layer' option from CREATE FOREIGN TABLE command. More info can be found [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/346-Querying-MS-Access-and-other-ODBC-data-sources-with-OGR_FDW.html).